# How does the author find $M_n(p)$ in the Toilet Paper Problem

Tags: probability, recurrence-relations, average

In [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2322567.pdf?refreqid=excelsior:6048393b5b3154372595b7a9586937ed), *The Toilet Paper Problem*, by D. Knuth, in the first page the author states that

> Let us assume that people enter the toilet stalls independently at
>   random, with probability $p$ that they are big-choosers and
>   probability $q = 1 - p$ that they are little-choosers. If the janitor
>   supplies a particular stall with two fresh rolls of toilet paper, both
>   of length $n$, let $M_n (p)$ be the average number of portions left on
>   one roll when the other roll first empties. (We assume that everyone
>   uses the same amount of paper, and that the lengths are expressed in
>   terms of this unit.) For example, it is easy to establish that
>
> $$M_1(p) = 1, \quad M_2(p) = 2-p, ...$$

, but how does he find $M_n(p)$ ?

I mean, if $n = 1$, people choose one of the stalls at random and since both stalls have 1 unit of paper, the other will be left with 1 unit of paper, hence $M_1(p) = 1$, but for other cases, I couldn't derive the relations clearly.

Comment: I ask this with extreme trepidation, but: What are big-choosers and little-choosers?

Comment: @BrianTung For example, big-choosers are the ones who chooses the roll with bigger size, i.e ". A big-chooser always takes a piece of toilet paper from the roll that is currently larger"

Comment: $n=2$,  one of them loose 1 portion for sure. İf next one is little chooser, 2 left on other one. Else, there is one left. So it is $2(1-p) + 1p$.

Comment: Are you asking about general $M_n(p)$ or the specific example cases we does like $M_1(p)$ and $M_n(0)$ etc. I can help with the base cases, but the general case is difficult and requires going through Knuth's whole paper--I'm not sure if he attained a closed answer or asymptotics.

Comment: @YacoubKureh Just the examples he gave, $M_2(p)$ and $M_3(p)$

Comment: @Atbey Why does that give the _average_ value ?

Comment: İt is the sum of values of events(2 and 1) times probability of events((1-p) and p), which is the definition of average(expected) value.

Answer (score 1):

Let's compute $M_2(p)$. We want the 'average' or 'expected' number of sheets left on one of the rolls when the other one is empty.

Starting both rolls with 2 sheets, label this $[2,2]$. The first person goes into the stall and uses one sheet. Regardless of who it is, big or small chooser, they take from second roll . So now we have $[2,1]$. The second user comes in. With probability $q=1-p$ they are small user so we end up with $[2,0]$. With probability $p$ they are big chooser so we end up with $[1,1]$. In that first scenario we terminate so with probability $q$ we are left with 2 sheets. In the second scenario it doesn't matter who comes in, by the end of the step we end up with $[1,0]$. Thus with probability $q$ we end with $[2,0]$ and with probability $p$ we end with $[1,0]$. And so on average we have $2q+p=2-2p+p=2-p$.

Try doing out $M_3(p)$. I recommend doing this with a tree diagram. Branching with the probabilities of big or small chooser and terminating a branch when a roll runs out.

For $M_n(0)$ this means we always have small choosers, so we get $[n,n]\rightarrow [n,n-1]\rightarrow [n,n-2]\rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow [n,0].$ And so $M_n(0)=n$. For $M_n(1)$, we always have big choosers so we have $[n,n]\rightarrow [n,n-1]\rightarrow [n-1,n-1]\rightarrow \cdots \rightarrow [1,1]\rightarrow [0,1].$

Comment: Even though you helped me to see the answer, your answer contains a lot of assumptions.

Comment: Could you please say more about what you mean by a lot of assumptions? Did I misunderstand the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Keeping track rather of both roll states as $M(a,b)$ with $0\le a\le b$, we find
$$M(a,b)=\begin{cases}(1-p)M(a-1,b)+pM(a,b-1)&0<a<b\\
M(a-1,a)&0<a=b\\
b&0=a(<b)\end{cases} $$
This is good enough to compute $M_n(p)=M(n,n)$ for small $n$, e.g., one quickly obtains
$$ M_{10}(p)=-1430p^{17} + 11440p^{16} - 39182p^{15} + 74074p^{14} - 82478p^{13} + 52426p^{12} - 15782p^{11} + 502p^{10} + 246p^9 + 118p^8 + 54p^7 + 22p^6 + 6p^5 - 2p^4 - 6p^3 - 8p^2 - 9p + 10$$

Comment: Those are also stated in the paper, but my question is **Why** ? In other words, why those formulates give us the average value ?

Comment: @onurcanbektas because e.g. the state $(a,b)$ with $0<a<b$ turns into state $(a-1,b)$ with probability $q$ and into state $(a,b-1)$ with probability $p$.